# Selenium has trouble recognizing elements in nested iFrames

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium Server to test a widget-based webpage.  All of the widgets are contained within an iFrame, and each widget contains its own iFrame.  I'm trying to manipulate elements within specific widgets specified by title, but Selenium seems to be unable to recognize anything past the second iFrame.

The title of the widget is within the first iFrame, and I need to use it to determine which iFrame to select next.  The code that I'm using to select the frame looks something like this:

```
selenium.selectFrame("css=div.widgetheader:contains(TITLE)+widgetbody iFrame);
```

However, when I attempt to access the elements within the iFrame, Selenium is unable to locate them.

Any thoughts on how to get Selenium to recognize the elements within this second frame?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to enter iframe that is nested inside another iframe, 2 iframe "switching" must be perform.
For example:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId1"))); //switching driver to first iframe
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId2"))); //switching driver to second iframe
//Now, do your stuff.
```

To return to initial location (pare, use:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Also, there can be situations when we not be able to get the iframe values. In this case, you can use tagName method.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe").get(0));
```